# Create/Include a modell for the whole controller in Codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter-4

i do my first steps in CI4.

Is there a way to define a modell into a controller for each functions of a controller one at one time?

At the moment i have to add the modell for each function as new like this

```
public function myfunction(){
   $myModel = new \App\Models\MyModel();
}
public function myfunction_two(){
   $myModel = new \App\Models\MyModel();
}
...
```

Update

Based on the answear i try this

```
class controllertwo extends BaseController
{
    private $myModel;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Add some Models we need in this controller?
        $this->myModel= new \App\Models\myModel();
        //$this->myModel= new myModel();
    }

...
```

The Codeigniter Errorconsole said "Use of undefined constant int - assumed 'int' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) " and markes this line "$this->myModel= new \App\Models\myModel();"

What i do wrong? Or is it not the best way to include a modell for all functions inside a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as a private variable in the controller as follow :

```
private $model;
```

Then set it in the constructor as follow:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new \App\Models\MyModel();
  }
```

Then simply refer to them in your methods as below:

```
public function myfunction(){
   $this->model ...
}
public function myfunction_two(){
    $this->model ...
}
```

Comment: i get this error: Use of undefined constant int - assumed 'int' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Can you update your code so i can help you out ?

Comment: Can you also add the error stack to the question? I don't see an issue with this code.

Comment: Also, check your model name, I am unsure if the model names are case sensitive.

Comment: wich kind of error informations i should provide?
additional to my post "SYSTEMPATH/Database/ModelFactory.php at line 76"

Comment: sorry, the problem comes from "protected $dateFormat = 'int';" inside the modell. This produced the errormessage. So i thank you for your help!